# How to join python list with escape characters?

Tags: python

This is very basic problem, but has been bugging my mind for few time.

I have a python list like this:

```py
lst = ['/', ',', ';', '-','+', ' and ']
```

## Required output

`'\/|\,|\;|\-\+` and so on.
i.e. add `\` in beginning and `|` in the end.
Basically, I am just trying to create a regex for them.

## My attempt

```py
['\' + i + '|' for i in lst ] # syntax error
['\\' + i + '|' for i in lst ] # wrong answer
```

## Update

I have fixed the typo. The main question is about why do I get the syntax error and cant simply use the list comprehension?

Comment: That output doesn't make sense. Why is `+` before `and`? Why is `,` before `;`? Where did `-` go?

Comment: Why don't you escape `and`?

Comment: you add ` \ ` to `and`. You should add it only to some element and later use `"|".join(your_list)`

Comment: @user2357112 is correct. Your question suggests you wish to omit `' and '` from the output, but your example attempts do nothing to accomplish that, which is inconsistent. Furthermore, you don't explain what output you get from the "wrong" attempt or *why* it is wrong. We are not being "finicky." We cannot know any details you don't tell us, and we avoid answering questions that are not clear because we may not provide you with a good one if we don't understand all the factors involved. You must be crystal clear about what your problem is if you expect someone to provide a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You get the syntax error with `'\'` because the backslash escapes the second quote, so it doesn't terminate the string. That's why you need to escape the backslash.

The list comprehension creates a list, it doesn't create a string.

Use `join` to combine the results of an iterator with a delimiter between each element.

Use `re.escape()` to add escapes that are required for a regular expression.

```
'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in lst)
```

Comment: @Axium Fixed that. Raw string doesn't work if there's a quote after the escape character.

Comment: I am a noob in python, I was trying to create regex pattern. `re.escape` solved my problem. Many many thanks.